# About $\infty$-norm on the space of convergent sequences

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $c$ be the space of all sequences that converge in $(\mathbb F,|\cdot|)$ where $\mathbb F$ is either $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$.

Endow $c$ with the norm $\|x\|=\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}|x_n|$. I am able to show that this defines a norm, but how can I show that this norm is well-defined? That is, how can I show that $\|x\|$ is finite for all $x\in c$?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say that you can show that this defines a norm but not that the norm is well-defined. There is no such thing as defining a norm that isn't well-defined.

Comment: A convergent sequence is bounded.

Answer (score 2):

If $x \rightarrow c$, then for some large enough $N$, we have that $|x_n - c| < 1$ for all $n \ge N$. So $\sup_{n \ge N} |x_n| \le |c| + 1 < \infty$. Also $\sup_{n < N} |x_n| < \infty$ since there are only finitely many terms here. So $\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} |
x_n| < \infty$.